# Replace not matching values with sub query in pl/sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle

Consider the following table

[image: Table]

```
SELECT QUEUENAME, 
       PRIORITY 
  FROM QUEUES 
 WHERE QUEUENAME IN ('Windows','Macintosh')
```

From the above query and table values, there is no `QueueName` as **"Macintosh"**. Thus i want whenever there is no values matched in the where clause a value with `QueueName` **"Unknown"** should be picked up and its value.

Please tell me how can i achieve this query?

The output i am looking for is

```
| QUEUENAME | PRIORITY |
|-----------|----------|
|   Windows |        1 |
|   Unknown |        3 |
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? You tagged your question with MySQL and SQL Server yet you mention PL/SQL which is Oracle's language for stored procedures but you don't show any procedural code.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED** Are you looking for something like this?

```
SELECT COALESCE(q.queuename, q2.queuename) queuename,
       COALESCE(q.priority, q2.priority) priority
  FROM 
(
  SELECT 'Windows' queuename FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Macintosh' FROM dual
) s LEFT JOIN queues q
    ON s.queuename = q.queuename JOIN queues q2
    ON q2.queuename = 'Unknown'
```

Output:

```
| QUEUENAME | PRIORITY |
|-----------|----------|
|   Windows |        1 |
|   Unknown |        3 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a4ec0/6)** demo (Oracle)
Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6f6a6/1)** demo (SQL Server)

Comment: i believe he is expecting the queuename when not matched should return the unknown row  He is expecting his result to display Unknown 3 & not Macintosh 3.   Correct me if i am wrong....

Comment: @peterm your post is useful but still it does not match to my output.

Comment: @KashifKhan Your desired output wasn't clear until you posted it. See updated answer with the fixed query.

Comment: @KashifKhan Did it help after all?

Answer (score 0):

```
create table queues as
select 'Windows' as queuename, 1 as priority from dual union all
select 'Linux'   as queuename, 2 as priority from dual union all
select 'Unknown' as queuename, 3 as priority from dual
;

with data_(qname) as (
select 'Windows'   from dual union all
select 'Macintosh' from dual
)
select coalesce(queues.queuename, default_.queuename) as queuename,
       coalesce(queues.priority, default_.priority) as priority
from data_
left outer join queues on queues.queuename = data_.qname
inner join queues default_ on default_.queuename = 'Unknown'
;

QUEUENA   PRIORITY
------- ----------
Windows      1
Unknown      3
```

Comment: This answer is for Oracle (11g). Me slow ... but I got it right in the first shot :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query

```
select * from queues where queuename in ('Windows','Macintosh')
UNION ALL
select * from queues where queuename in 
(
select decode
(
(
select count(queuename) from queues 
where queuename NOT IN  ('Windows','Macintosh')
),1,NULL,'Unknown')
queuename from queues where queuename NOT in ('Windows','Macintosh'))
```

The query gives your expected result

If you give windows Macintosh it gives windows unknown.
If you give linux macintosh it gives linux unknown
if you give windows unknown it gives windows unknown
If you give Linux unknown it gives linux unknown
If you give linux windows it gives linux windows

I am writing codes for oracle only for the past 4 months, so some experienced can give a much more simple code than this...

And you have to give the where in 3 places